# Arraylist<Interger> vs int[] list = new int[3];

Tags: java, arraylist, int

the problem follows. When I use `int[] list = new int[3]` then `list.length` works, but if I use `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` `list.length` does not work, I'm new and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `list.`[size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size())  instead.